# How to Export Drupal 6 datas to Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, export

The web development firm we hired few years ago to build our site used Drupal 6. Its a very customized drupal website running with different modules and customized dashboard.

By the way, I am a graphic designer with some CSS/PHP knowledge, and I am in charge with the website content update.

I do not have any knowledge about Drupal theming, so they sent me to a Drupal training course that teaches how to make themes in Drupal. But the training course is teaching Drupal 7 not the Drupal 6.

Just wondering how can I Export the datas (company products data content & images) used? Is there a Module that can read datas from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are modules that exists ([Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d), [Data Export](https://drupal.org/project/data_export_import), [Migrate](https://drupal.org/migrate)), however the more customized your original Drupal 6 site is, the harder it becomes to easily transfer data.

I would try with some of these modules and see how they perform based on your exact scenario - you may be lucky and it will all work fine.

If it doesn't then you have to take a more manual / custom approach. I've done this before by exporting data from the old site to a csv with a custom script, and then writing another custom script to import the data into the new site. This can handle complex relationships that generic import / export modules can't cope with, but takes longer and requires a more intimate knowledge of how Drupal works.